# Is there an option to run command line through web browser?

Tags: linux, frontend

Like in the topic. Is there an option to use pure javascript to run command line through the web page? No PHP or Node is allowed. Command line must be run on the client side.

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript, depending on what you want to achieve it might be possible to create something that looks like a shell.

Answer (score -1):

Answers is you can't do it with just **HTML web page**, with help of JavaScript you can.

HTML is not programming language, yes i repeat HTML is not a programming or scripting languag. Actually HTML is just a data formating tool. Sole purpose of HTML is of data representation not data interpretation. HTML stands for **hyper text markup language**. It is a markup language. A markup language is a language that is to sort and format data. So rather than dumping plain text to the browser we can format it to an extent with HTML. HTML was never meant to be a programming language. You cannot even find the sum of 2 numbers with HTML.

You can run commands only by using programming languges.

However, pleasee see these useful [link](https://www.htmlexe.com/help/comline) from htmlexe: Command Line Options To Manage Project Files.

Comment: Yes, it's JS, but OP asks about running command line through the web page - read the OP carefully.

Comment: The fact that you cannot run local commands from a web page has nothing to do with the fact that HTML is a markup language. Nor will using Javascript help.